# Google Analytics and Demographics in Android "Invalid Action"

Tags: android, cordova, google-analytics, google-analytics-firebase

I have a Cordova app working in production, with google Analytics implemented, and now, my client have asked me to enable demographics data collection.

I am trying to make it work in Android, so I followed this guide to enable it in the console:

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2819948?hl=en&ref_topic=2799375

I also added the android Code the way that this link says under the android label:

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2444872?hl=en&utm_id=ad#app

So my function is like this (in Android Plugin):

```
 private void enableAdIdCollection(Boolean isEnabled, CallbackContext callbackContext) {
        if (! trackerStarted ) {
            callbackContext.error("Tracker not started");
            return;
        }


        tracker.enableAdvertisingIdCollection(true);
        callbackContext.success((isEnabled ? "En" : "Dis")+ "abled ad id collection for Display Advertisement");
    }
```

I dont initialize the tracker because it is also initialized previously under the tracker variable.

When I run the app, I have the next output in the logcat

```
12-01 15:13:37.041: W/CordovaPlugin(461): Attempted to send a second callback for ID: UniversalAnalytics1790405607
12-01 15:13:37.041: W/CordovaPlugin(461): Result was: "Invalid action"
```

And I dont have idea how can I fix this. My analytics version is GAv4. ¿Somebody have found this issue?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this @Del? I'm hitting the same error.